# How to use a .click function in jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

The following code should add 100 to an existing number in a mysql table if the button gets clicked. If I click the button nothing happens, but if I reload the page the function adds 100 to the number. What is wrong with my code?

```
<?php
define('DBHOST', 'localhost');
define('DBUSER', 'root');
define('DBPASS', '123');
define('DBNAME', 'dbtest');

$conn = mysql_connect(DBHOST,DBUSER,DBPASS);
$dbcon = mysql_select_db(DBNAME);
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Test</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.8/css/materialize.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<a id="button" class="waves-effect btn deep-orange darken-1">Button 1</a>
</body>

<script>
$("#button").click(function(){
  <?php
  mysql_query("UPDATE users SET test = (test + 100) WHERE userId=1");
  ?>
});
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: You made my day >.<

Comment: It doesn't work that way. Javascript is client side code and only runs on the client (the browser connecting to your server). PHP is server side code and only runs on the server and can never be seen by the client.

Comment: @DelightedD0D - when the OP understands that, the world of googling and debugging will again make sense.  this is a simple question of orientation - short and sweet is the answer, not confusing links.

Comment: ah ok, so the server just executes the php command and thats it.

Comment: Take a look at the source code of your rendered page :)

Comment: Yep I got it, sorry if it was a dumb question ^^

Comment: @WEBjuju I would be inclined to agree if you had mentioned `Ajax` in your answer as a nudge in the right direction. Your statement makes perfect sense as a comment, it just wasnt really an *answer* IMHO

Comment: the question was What is wrong with my code? yo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant call PHP code from a jQuery function like that. All the php runs when the page loads and thats it. You can however use jQuery and Ajax to send a message to a php script that processes that message then returns a response. The script can even be in the same actual file like you have (or in a different file altogether) something like this would do:

```
<?php
define('DBHOST', 'localhost');
define('DBUSER', 'root');
define('DBPASS', '123');
define('DBNAME', 'dbtest'); 
$conn = mysql_connect(DBHOST,DBUSER,DBPASS);
$dbcon = mysql_select_db(DBNAME);

if(isset($_POST['updateTest']){
    $val = $_POST['test'];
    $id + $_POST['userId'];
    // validate inputs and such....
    mysql_query("UPDATE users SET test = (test + 100) WHERE userId=1");
    // send success or error response...
    echo json_encode(['success'=>true]);
    exit; 
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Test</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.8/css/materialize.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<a id="button" class="waves-effect btn deep-orange darken-1">Button 1</a>
</body>

<script>
$("#button").click(function(){ 
   var count = 100;
   var userId = 1;
   var dataObject= {updateTest: true, test: 100, userId: 1};
   $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     // url: "page.php", // add this line to send to some page other than the this one
     data: dataObject,
     success: function(response) {
        if(response.success){
              alert('test worked');
        }
        else{
             alert('there was an error')
        }
     },
     error: function(xhr, status, error) { 
         console.log(xhr);
     }
   });    
});
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by the previous poster PHP is server side and Javascript client side so what is actually happening is the following.

When the page is returned back to the user your piece of javascript just looks like the below..

Your MySQL statement here has executed already it can not interact with client side code in this way

```
<script>
$("#button").click(function(){
  // nothing here.. But your MYSQL statement has executed anyway
});
</script>
```

Comment: Just like the previous answer, while this is true, you should really offer an option that would complete the task at hand.